# Divisibility of product

Tags: number-theory

My classmate asked this question:

> Whether for any n, there exists $0<t_1<t_2<...<t_n$ such that for any $0<a<b<lcm(t_1,t_2,...,t_n)$ , $\prod_{i=1}^n(a+t_i)\nmid\prod_{i=1}^n(b+t_i)$

I tried some small n, for every $n\le 18$, there exists such $t_1,...,t_n$. When n=18, $(t_1,t_2,...,t_n)=(1,2,3,4,5,6,8,10,12,15,20,24,30,48,60,80,120 ,240)$

is a solution.